# DC motor-gearbox - torque and time to lift load

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have a power supply that can provide 12 V up to 0.2 A. There is a spool connected to the shaft of the gearbox connected to the motor. The radius of this spool is 0.1 m and the system needs to lift 3 kg.

I am trying to find a gear ratio in terms of DC motor constants, the time it takes to lift the mass 1 m, and the motor efficiency. I am also assuming a steady-state model and negligible friction.

So far, I got the torque generated by the mass as
$$
\tau = mgr =  2.943\ \mathrm{Nm}
$$

So I was thinking the gear ratio would be

$$
\tau = k_t\cdot i_m : 2.943
$$

Then, I calculated

$$
w_{motor} = P_{motor}/\tau = 0.8155\ \mathrm{rad/s}
$$

Lastly, the time to lift the mass 1 m as
$$
10/0.8155 = 12.26\ \mathrm{s},
$$
where 10 is the arc length

Is this correct? I feel as if I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting into the gearing weeds far too early.

Your power supply can deliver 12 V at 0.2 A, or up to 2.4 watts.

At this power level, a 50% efficient motor would be very good going, so let's assume you can do mechanical work at 1.2 W.

A mass of 3 kg needs 30 N to lift. To lift it through 1 m needs 30 J.

30 J at 1.2 watts takes 30/1.2 = 25 seconds to deliver.

It looks like the only significant difference between my power/energy route and yours is the 50% motor efficiency assumption, so your sums could well be right. However, choosing a gear ratio first seems to me to be doing it backwards.

- The power calculation gives you the time to raise the weight.
- Choose a lifting pulley diameter that's mechanically convenient.
- Those two will give you the pulley's angular speed.
- That defines your gear ratio, to match the pulley speed to the motor's best efficiency speed.